# My Toshiba Satellite 580GB drive continues to loose about 30GB and 20GB a day

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, incremental-backup, toshiba-hard-drive

I have been backing up the entire C: drive on a WD Passport** - also have moved almost 900GB to a Seagate Free Agent GoFlex 3TB drive, which I use almost exclusively for Movie and Video files (Panasonic) On my C: drive I have 128GB of My Pictures (quite a bit of Video (Cannon)) and on My Video I have reduced it to only 78GB My Music and all my programs, etc. I have 30GB in the Windows folder and I think are around 25GB for the rest, so where are the 'missing' 200+GB? How do I see? How do I do a 'master' sort of file size for every thing?  I do not do system backups on my C: drive.  I get 25GB from Norton - at one time it covered all my Pics, now I guess all non-Pictures and Videos files. 
** The WD Backup window shows almost 900GB copied, but I believe this is the second and triple backups & there is over 200GB of Other - which I guess I am looking for

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected free disk space decrease?](http://superuser.com/questions/260285/unexpected-free-disk-space-decrease)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest 2 actions to get a clear picture of what is on your disk:

A) Run **[WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/)** which will give you a complete picture regarding all system and user files on the disk.If you have big colored chunks on the picture, you can click on them and it will tell you above what it is.

B) Run the command below in an elevated command prompt. That will tell you the allocated space for shadowstorage (that's where system restore points are being kept). This space is not shown in the WinDirStat list.

**vssadmin list shadowstorage**